# how to create build definitions without repository access (in visual studio online)

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

We want to hire some external people to help us in building automated tests. For this reason they need the possibility to create/edit builds, but we don't want to grant read permissions to the repositories (source code).

In our tests we are only successful in creating builds and release with access permissions to the repository. As soon we deny the permissions to the "Code" hub, we can't work on with builds...

Is this even possible? 
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it’s impossible.

If the external people need to create, edit or queue a build while the they do not have permission to read the repo for build, VSTS will prevent the these users to create, edit or queue the build. They need the read permission for the build repo (branch) at least.